# Ironic constructions in German

Tags: english-to-german

As part of my masters in linguistics, I am taking a course on the subject of irony. We were given examples of sentences that are most likely ironic, as the English sentence "he is not exceptionally smart" (which has the structure "he is not exceptionally X"). This does not mean literally that he is smart at an exceptional level, but rather, ironically, that he is very stupid.

Are there similar constructions in German, preferably ones that involve superlative and negation?

Comment: We are Germans. We do not joke, we do not laugh and we are not ironic. Never.

Comment: @JohnSmithers Darüber kann ich nicht lachen!

Comment: it is true that it does not literally mean that he is exceptionally smart as it does literally mean that is is NOT exceptionally smart ;).... there is no real ironic twist here. If anything I would call that sarcasm but it could also be real empathy that keeps you from saying "He is a dumbass."

Comment: I should have read the answers before commenting... guess I am the one you are talking about with that one sentence :D

Comment: I would also call your example more sarcasm than irony, because if it would be ironic it would express the opposite of the literal terms.

Comment: Er ist ein Blitzmerker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ironie, im Englischen wie im Deutschen, bedeutet in aller Regel das Gegenteil von dem zu sagen, was man wirklich zum Ausdruck bringen möchte; in einer Art und Weise, die dem aufmerksamen Leser / Zuhörer die eigentliche, versteckte Bedeutung offenbart.

Was zunächst die Frage aufwirft: ist

> He is not exceptionally smart.

tatsächlich im Englischen als Ironie zu verstehen? Im Sinne von

> (superficial meaning) He is very smart, but not exceptionally so.
>
> (hidden meaning) He is rather stupid.

Selbst wenn dem so ist: die hier zum Teil angebotene Übersetzung

> Er ist nicht besonders schlau.

und ihre Varianten würden im Deutschen nie als Ironie verstanden, sondern als einfache Aussage.

Eine Übertreibung *ohne* Negierung funktioniert, zumindest im Deutschen, sehr viel besser um Ironie auszudrücken:

> Er ist ein ganz besonders Schlauer.

Hier ist, spätestens mit Kontext und Betonung, ganz klar: man sagt A, meint aber das Gegenteil von A.

Comment: Aber ohne Negierung... wäre das nicht einfach als sarkastisch gemeint und nicht ironisch? Und zwar weiß ich es nicht, was der Unterschied zwischen Ironie und Sarkasmus ist.

Comment: Ironie ist Verstellung, Verdrehung, also etwas anderes sagen, als man meint. Sarkasmus ist versteckter Spott, also Spott, der durch Ironie zum Ausdruck gebracht wird.

Comment: "sondern als einfache Aussage" - "Er ist nicht besonders schlau, wenn er im Flugzeug ein Fenster öffnet." bedeutet im Deutschen natürlich auch "Er ist ziemlich dumm."

Answer (score 3):

Irony or sarcasm? I'm not always clear on the distinction. I have a feeling that Answers to this Question could run dozens of pages long.

Affirmations can be used to mean the opposite, for example.

> In der Tat (indeed). Sicher doch (of course, certainly).

One German stand-up comic became famous for `Riiichtisch (= richtig; yeah right)`.

`Das haben Sie fein gemacht`: If your boss tells you that, you should be worried. (Situational context and tone of voice matter.)

`He is not exceptionally smart` has a counterpart in `Er ist nicht besonders clever` or sometimes `Er ist nicht besonders helle` (the latter being even more dismissive of the person's intelligence).

If you say `Ich würde Herrn X nicht unbedingt widersprechen` (I wouldn't necessarily disagree with Mr. X) and then proceed to demolish Mr. X's argument, context reveals your true intent.

You ask about superlatives and negation.

`Großschriftsteller` (major writer) is one timely example. `Suboptimal` means lousy, awful. If I think of more examples I'll add them later.

**EDIT:** There was something about your question that bugged me and I can think I can put my finger on it now. I'm not entirely sure* that the *construction* `He is not exceptionally X` is inherently ironic. To me, it takes a bit more (tone, context) than the bare naked construction to convey the speaker's intent. What do others think?

*And I do mean "not entirely sure"; I'm not being sarcastic :)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I agree, that isn't ironic. In German also, because you technically say what you mean. Irony - imho - lives from the idea not to say what you mean but to stress your words that it is obvious. So I would say *Er ist nicht besonders helle* is more sarcastic while *Du bist ja ein ganz Schlauer* or *Du bist ja ein Fuchs* are ironic.

Comment: `"Er ist nicht helle"` ist überhaupt nicht ironisch, weil genau das ja gesagt werden soll. Sagt man, `er sei nicht der Hellsten einer` läßt das, rein wörtlich betrachtet, die Möglichkeit zu, er stünde aber quasi in der zweiten Reihe, oder sei durchschnittlich schlau. Gesagt werden soll aber, dass er alles andere als schlau ist, und daher ist es Ironie, wenn man den Superlativ verneint.

Answer (score 2):

> He is not exceptionally smart.

kann mit

> Er ist nicht der Hellste.

übersetzt werden, oder mit

> Er ist nicht gerade außerordentlich clever.
>
> Er ist kein Weltmeister in Sachen Cleverness.
>
> Er hat die Arbeit nicht erfunden.

Im Großen und Ganzen gilt, dass sich die Sätze leicht übertragen lassen, und keiner speziellen Fachkenntnis bedürfen, weil Ironie im Deutschen genauso funktioniert.

Comment: "Er ist nicht ein Weltmeister in Sachen Cleverneß." ist meiner Meinung keine adäquate Übersetzung für "He is not exceptionally smart." Wenn überhaupt, dann hieße es "kein" anstelle von "nicht ein" heißen, aber auch diese Übersetzung klingt ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @MariusSchulz: Es soll auch keine möglichst eng geführte Übersetzung sein, sondern was als Nebenfrage formuliert war beantworten: eine ähnliche Konstruktion sein mit Superlativ und Negation, wobei "exceptionally" selbst ja kein Superlativ ist.

Answer (score 2):

The irony in German phrases needs to be a bit more obvious to be understood - We tend to take words probably more literally and there needs to be "some flag" waving that the sentence is meant to be ironic.

So "Er war nicht besonders klug" is not *necessarily* understood to be ironic, but could also mean exactly what it says.

"Er war nicht besonders helle" has a small flag on it due to the non-usual expression for "klug"

"Er hat die Weisheit nicht mit Löffeln gefressen" has someone waving a huge flag for irony and would boil down to the same meaning, but the wording makes it very clear that it means to say the exact opposite of "Er ist klug".

The size and explicity of the hint depends on context and situation, but my feeling says that in everyday conversation it needs to be a bit bigger in German than in English.

Answer (score 1):

I am German - and I think the way you put irony together with politeness is something typical english. "The queen is not amused" for "she is angry about it" is something we do not have an equivalent for. "He is not exceptionally smart" is - as far as I know - not exactly "he is dumb". It is a polite way to say that he is not one of the smartest people you ever met - and everybody knows that you imply he IS in fact dumb - but you would never say this directly (in english). You make others smile about the sentence, not about the person you speak about. It is possible to express this in German, but there is no standard-construct, there is much left to HOW you say it. When you read german blogs - for example - we have to put a lot of smileys into the text to make the others understand that we do not want to hurt, because the CONSTRUCT in itself does not provide this detail.

To come close we could possibly say: "Vermutlich ist er nicht der Schlaueste."

Comment: `Der Chef war nicht begeistert` wird wohl von den meisten ironisch benutzt und verstanden.